Having issue with YOY query
I have following YOY query, works fine but the vendors which are not common is missing from the final result, can anyone please guide on what am I doing wrong?
SELECT `current_period`.`vendor_name` AS `VendorName`, 
       `current_period`.`total_sales` AS `current_total_sales`, 
        IFNULL(last_year_period.total_sales, 0) AS last_year_total_sales, 
        ROUND(((current_period.total_sales-IFNULL(last_year_period.total_sales, 0))/IFNULL(last_year_period.total_sales, 0))*100, 2) as sales_yoy, 
       `current_period`.`total_quantity` AS `current_total_quantity`, 
        IFNULL(last_year_period.total_quantity, 0) AS last_year_total_quantity, 
        ROUND(((current_period.total_quantity-IFNULL(last_year_period.total_quantity, 0))/IFNULL(last_year_period.total_quantity, 0))*100, 2) as units_yoy
FROM ( SELECT manufacturer_key, 
             `manufacturer_dimension`.`vendor_name`, 
              SUM((CASE WHEN row_type = '1' && is_reprint = '0' THEN charged_amount WHEN row_type = '2' && row_sub_type = '1' && is_reprint = '0' THEN (-1 * charged_amount) ELSE 0 END)) AS total_sales, 
              SUM((CASE WHEN row_type = '1' && is_reprint = '0' THEN qty WHEN row_type = '2' && row_sub_type = '1' && is_reprint = '0' THEN (-1 * qty) ELSE 0 END)) AS total_quantity
              FROM product_facts
              JOIN ( SELECT id as i_time_key, 
                            CONVERT (full_date, DATE) AS full_date 
                     FROM time_dimension
                    ) AS time_dimension ON product_fact.time_key=time_dimension.i_time_key
              JOIN ( SELECT id as i_manufacturer_key, 
                            name as vendor_name 
                     FROM manufacturer_dimension 
                    ) AS manufacturer_dimension ON product_fact.manufacturer_key=manufacturer_dimension.i_manufacturer_key
       WHERE  time_dimension.full_date BETWEEN '2024-10-18' AND DATE_ADD('2024-10-19', INTERVAL 0 DAY) 
       GROUP BY manufacturer_key
      ) AS current_period
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT manufacturer_key, 
                  `manufacturer_dimension`.`vendor_name`, 
                   SUM((CASE WHEN row_type = '1' && is_reprint = '0' THEN charged_amount WHEN row_type = '2' && row_sub_type = '1' && is_reprint = '0' THEN (-1 * charged_amount) ELSE 0 END)) AS total_sales, 
                   SUM((CASE WHEN row_type = '1' && is_reprint = '0' THEN qty WHEN row_type = '2' && row_sub_type = '1' && is_reprint = '0' THEN (-1 * qty) ELSE 0 END)) AS total_quantity
            FROM product_fact
            JOIN ( SELECT id as i_time_key, 
                          CONVERT (full_date, DATE) AS full_date 
                   FROM time_dimension
                  ) AS time_dimension ON product_fact.time_key=time_dimension.i_time_key
            JOIN ( SELECT id as i_manufacturer_key, 
                          name as vendor_name FROM manufacturer_dimension
                  ) AS manufacturer_dimension ON product_fact.manufacturer_key=manufacturer_dimension.i_manufacturer_key
            WHERE  time_dimension.full_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB('2024-10-18', INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AND DATE_SUB('2024-10-19', INTERVAL 1 YEAR) 
            GROUP BY manufacturer_key
         ) AS last_year_period ON current_period.manufacturer_key = last_year_period.manufacturer_key


Should probably be a full outer join between current_period and last_year_period.

i tried full outer join but gives syntax error, am using mysql and MySQL does not explicitly support a FULL OUTER JOIN

If you want ALL vendors to appear, regardless of whether they have data in either of the years, then you'd need to start with just a select of the vendor codes/names and then left join off that with the sales results from the different periods

The query does not seem to need time_dimension or manufacturer_dimension.  There are two different dates; consider adding/subtradting INTERVAL 1 DAY.  Watch out for items occurring at midnight; BETWEEN is _inclusive.  If time_dimensionsplits up aDATETIME`, beware -- it is often clumsy and less efficient than other techniques.
